# Piping output from awk to perl

Tags: perl, parsing, unix, awk, pipe

I want to make an array in Perl with the values obtained from my awk script. Then I can do math on them in Perl.

Here is my Perl, which runs a program, which saves a text file:

```
my $unix_command_dsc = (`./program -s test.fasta saved_file.txt`);
my $dsc_run = qx($unix_command_dsc);
```

Now I have some Awk that parses that data saved in the text file:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN{       # Initialize the values to zero. Note, done automatically also.
    sumc4 = 0
    sumc5 = 0
    sumc6 = 0
}

/^[1-9][0-9]* residue/ {next}    #Match line that begins with number and has word 'residue', skip it.
/^[1-9]/ {                       #Match line that begins with number.

    sumc4 += $4                  #Add up the values of the nth column into the variables.
    sumc5 += $5
    sumc6 += $6

    print $4 "\t" $5 "\t" $6    #This will show the whole columns. 

    }

END{
    print "sum H" "\t" "sum E" "\t" "sum C"
    print sumc4 "\t" sumc5 "\t" sumc6  
}
```

I run this Awk from terminal with the following commands:

```
./awk_program.txt saved_file.txt
```

Any ideas how I would gather this data from the print statements in awk into arrays in perl?

What I've tried is to just run that awk script in perl:

```
my $unix_command_awk = (`./awk_program.txt saved_file.txt`);
my $awk_run = qx($unix_command_awk);
```

But perl gives me errors and commands not found, like it thinks the data are commands. Should there be a STDOUT in the awk that I'm missing, rather than print?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just reimplement the logic in Perl. It will roughly take the same amount of code as the awk code and you would not need to call external processes and parse the result afterwards.

Comment: So I will still have to parse the result, even though I did that in awk? Is there are way to make a list in awk [value1, value2...] and then be able to use that list in perl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should just be:

```
my $awk_run = `./awk_program.txt saved_file.txt`;
```

Backticks tell perl to run the command and return the output.  So your assignment to $unix_command_awk is running the command, and then `qx($unix_command_awk)` executes the output as a new command.

Comment: Yep, I just made $awk_run an @array variable and I got what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Pipe from awk to your perl script:

```
./awk_program file.txt | perl perl-script.pl
```

Then read from stdin inside the perl:

```
while (<>) {
    # do stuff with $_
    my @cols = split(/\t/);
}
```

Comment: I get sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable